# AJAX (Raw JS): Upload Image

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I am new to ajax (and try to avoid frameworks), I tried to check through PHP if any file is set and show `true` or `false`, but it didn't worked so I wonder what I did wrong.

This is my code, HTML and JS:

```
<form class="file-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="post.php">
    <input type="file" name="fu-obj" id="fu-obj" />
    <div data-file-upload><!-- Output here: "True" Or "False" if file isset --></div>
    <script>
        // "fu" - file upload
        var fu = {
            response: document.querySelector('[data-file-upload]'),
            ele: document.querySelector('[name="fu-obj"]')
        };

        fu['ele'].onblur = function() {
            if(fu['ele'].files.length > 0) {
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
                        fu['response'].innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                }
                ajax.open('POST', 'post.php', true);
                ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
                ajax.send('fu-obj='+fu['ele'].files[0].name);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <!-- If ajax doesn't work -->
    <button type="submit">Manual Upload</button>
</form>
```

- the `post.php` file is really simple and don't do yet any action, only contains an `if()` statement `if(isset($_POST['fu-obj'])) { echo 'True'; } else { echo 'False'; }` to check if it works

**UPDATE** I've replaced `$_POST` with `$_FILES`, when I send it manually it works (but not with ajax)

**UPDATE 2** - ajax.js:

```
var ajax;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    // Microsoft IE (5,6)
    ajax = new ActiveXObject();
}
```

How can I solve this issue? Thank you very much!

(Please, don't suggest jQuery solutions, even if it's easier)

Comment: Did you try using the `FormData` built-in object? [This is a pretty good tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax)

Comment: @nicovank Not yet

Comment: Once try replacing `fu['ele'].files[0].name` with some string like 'fu-obj=1234'

Comment: @Nandan didn't work

Comment: ajax is undefined.

Comment: `var params = JSON.stringify({ fu-obj: 'Your value'});` and `ajax.send(params);` In php just `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` We can see everything which is being posted.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. ajax is defined in a file called ajax.js

Comment: Getting the response, so Ajax must be defined

Comment: @Nandan Please see my updates

Comment: Just before you make the ajax call, have you tried logging `fu['ele'].files[0].name` ?

Comment: I didn't use console.log but I tried to alert it (`alert(fu['ele'].files[0].name`) and I do get the file name

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
> ```

You claim you are sending `multipart/form-data`

> ```
> ajax.send('fu-obj='+fu['ele'].files[0].name);
> ```

Then you send (possibly invalid because you forgot to use `encodeURIComponent`) data encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

PHP then fails to decode the data because it tries to use the wrong encoding.

Put the correct content-type in the first line I quoted.

---

You could scrap the XHR entirely. Passing a string to the server to see if the string has been set is an expensive operation. You could just as easily do this in plain JS:

```
if (fu['ele'].files[0]) { ... }
```

Comment: I removed but still getting "False"

Comment: Is `false` your response ? Why don't you show your post.php  ?

Comment: @Nandan I wrote it with my question: `if(isset($_POST['fu-obj'])) { echo 'True'; } else { echo 'False'; }`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to pass files to the server with ajax, (not encode it as a uri)

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
        fu['response'].innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
}
ajax.open('POST', 'post.php', true);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('fu-obj[]', fu['ele'].files[0], fu['ele'].files[0].name);
ajax.send(data);
```

Also, "ajax" is undefined in your code, so define it.

Comment: I tried with `$_POST` and `$_FILES` but still nothing :\

Comment: then something else is wrong with your code. this is the correct way to upload files programmatically. try logging things to the console until you find it. do some debugging and let us know where the problem is.

Comment: Console: `ReferenceError: form is not defined` (`var data = new FormData(form);`) (fixed)

Comment: @natanel97 - whoops. my fault. form doesn't belong there. see the edit.

Comment: also who downvoted my correct answer and upvoted the other incorrect answer??

Comment: Even if i wanted to, I can't downvote your answer (or someone else answer)... you can be sure it wasn't me.

Comment: @natanel97 - I know it wasn't you. I just didn't have my [downvote watcher](https://github.com/Pamblam/WhoDownvotedMe.js) turned on so i was curious if Quentin voted out of spite for me pointing out his answer was wrong. anyway. did it help when you removed the "form" part?

Comment: LOL why does no one told me about this feature (downvote watcher)
about the form part: I'm still getting `false`. i guess i'll just remove all and start over in a different way or maybe i'll try some tutorial

Comment: Its not a feature its just a little hack i wrote to see who was downvoting my perfectly good answers. Good luck man.